# Input length is undifined

Tags: javascript, css, html, input

< **Why Input Length Is Undifined**

**Js**

```
function calc() {
var inp = document.getElementById("inp");
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var inpval = inp.value

result.innerHTML = inpval;
        alert(inp.length);
}
```

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="inp" class="inp" Type="number"/>
        <center>
            <div id="calc" class="calc" onclick="calc()">Calculate</div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <p id="result"></p>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me with this code I don't know why I am getting this error whenever I click on function it always shows undifined

Comment: inpval.length vs inp.length?

Comment: `inp` is a dom element so it doesnt have a  `length` property.

Comment: inp is a html element its not an array and hence does not have any length property  thats whyy you are getting undefiend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`getElementbyId`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) and the `Element` has no `length` property. **This is the reason why that output is `undefined`.** So if you want to get the length of the value of the input element, you have to access [input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) with value property like `inp.value` or `inpval`.

After then, you can get the length of that like `inp.value.length` or `inpval.length`.